# React Native fetch is not a function

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

I'm trying to use react native for a simple app. I want to download a json array from a page and display it as a listview.
I'm doing this

```
var listApp = React.createClass({

fetchData : function() {
  fetch(requestURL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.log(responseData);
    })
    .done();
},
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.fetchData();
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(elements)
  });
},
```

But doing this I get the error `fetch is not a function` from Chrome debugger. I get fetch in this way `var fetch = require("fetch");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to `require` it. It's a polyfill for the browser version, and like the browser version it's always available to the global scope.

Comment: Page not found, "Movies example", Please update your answer.